# AWS caller identity issues. I am not able to receive an output

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

AWS sts get-caller-identity error

```sh
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

This command is giving me this in return:

`Unknown output type`

I have not given anything as an output.

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure your .aws/credentials file has valid content:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ********************
aws_secret_access_key = ***************************************
aws_session_token = **********************************************
```

Where the asterisks are your actual keys and token.
Next, run the following command from your terminal (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html):

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

It will output your UserId, Account and ARN.
If this still does not work,
run the `aws configure` command (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html), manually supplying the keys, default region and default output format (e.g. JSON, YAML or text format), then run the STS command again.